# How to version a field in avro schema when Kafka Consumer updates?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

Example :- I have a field named

```
"abc":[
   {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}, 
   {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}
]
```

Consumer1, consumer2 consuming this variable, where as now consumer2 require few more fields and need to change the structure.

How to address this issue by following best practice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`type map`](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Maps) in Avro schema. `key` is always a `string` and `value` can be any type but should one type for the whole map.

So, in your case, introduce a map into your schema. `consumer_1` can consume the event and get they keys needed only for the `consumer_1` and do the same for `consumer_2`. But still same Avro schema.

Note: *you can not send null to the map in schema. you need to send empty map.*

Comment: I have introduced a new variable for the new changes to support both the consumers. Once all the consumers consumes latest field we can remove the old field.

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Comment: Yes, We can do this as well if we don't have consumers consuming already, Since it is a datatype change it will break the contract for existing  consumers.

Answer (score 0):

If possible introduce Schema Registry server for schema versioning. Register all the different avro schema's at schema registry and a version Id will be given.  Connect your producer and consumer app with schema registry server to fetch the registered schema for the respective Kafka message. Now message with any kind of schema can be received by any consumer with full compatibility.